# Linq Where clause with Generics does not reconize Equals base type

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have the following simple function:

```
public class BaseEntityRepository<TEntity, TId> : IBaseEntityRepository<TEntity, TId>
    where TEntity : class, TBaseEntity, IIdentifiedEntity<TId>
    where TId : struct {
//...
    public virtual TEntity GetById(TId id) {
        return (from e in GetAll() where e.Id.Equals(id) select e).SingleOrDefault();
    }
//...
}
```

Since TId is a generic I'm receiving the following message:

**"Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."**

No matter what type it represent. I've tried "Byte", "Int16", "Int32", "Long"... The message is the same.
I thought that defining the generic constraint as struct would be enought to the type be reconized as a primitive.

BTW... GetAll() returns an `IQueryable<TEntity>`.

Anyway... Does anybody know an workaround?
Thanks

Comment: You write that `GetAll` returns `IQueryable<TEntity>`. Is that also how it is *declared* (perhaps that is what you mean)?

Comment: there isn't an easy (any?) way to constrain to a primitive type; also consider that `string` is a primitive, but not a `struct`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about IEquatable?

```
where TId : IEquatable<TId>
```

Comment: That seams to solve it. The final constraint became:

public class BaseEntityRepository<TEntity, TId> : IBaseEntityRepository<TEntity, TId>
    where TEntity : class, TBaseEntity, IIdentifiedEntity<TId>
    where TId : struct, IEquatable<TId> {

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess. What if you tried this?

```
e.Id.GetHashCode() == id.GetHashCode()
```

Comment: I'm not confident that the comparission of hashcodes can guarantee the identity of two Ids since the Id can be anything. It could be Ok for integers values, but I'm not sure about Guids or Strings.